# RFID card reader Samsung galaxy tab

Tags: usb, samsung

I developed an Android app for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 in Android 4.4. Now I'm trying to connect a RFID card reader through my microUSB port to emulate a keyboard so we can read different tags which contain different info. I'm using the Syris RD200-M1-G reader. I searched a lot in the internet and I read that is compatible with Android. My problem is that I connect it to my tab and the reader is powered off and I can't do anythyng.

Do I need something to power it? or maybe in my program code? Any help will be so appreciated. Thank you very much.

P.S: I'm using a Samsung smt-530 galaxy tab 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I must unmark your question. The reason is that finally I could connect my RFID tag reader. The problem was the usb wire that I was using. Today I bought a new USB OTG wire and it's working perfectly.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you for sharing your solution with the community :) btw, you can mark your own answer as the correct answer so future readers can see which solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your [reader gets it's power through USB](http://www.syris.info/reader/USB-RFID-reader/RD200-M1.html) and Android devices needs to support [usb on-the-go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) to be able to power other devices through USB. [Your tablet apparently doesn't support this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_4_7.0).